# Make [debouncing] a synonym for [debounce]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I suggest making [debouncing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debouncing) a synonym for [debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debounce):

- Debounce has more entries, so it should take priority
- Adding "ing" to a term just makes the word longer to no benefit.

I'd steal the description from debouncing ("Debouncing ensures that exactly one signal is sent for an event that may be happening several times."), since debounce lacks a description.

Looking through various entries, both names refer to the same thing.

Comment: Seems clearly reasonable.  I'll do it in a couple days if no objections are raised.

Comment: What does it mean? The [electrical type](http://www.ganssle.com/debouncing.htm) (dealing with (switch) debouncing in software)? The [JavaScripty type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/can-someone-explain-the-debounce-function-in-javascript)?

Comment: Or in other words, it is time to create the tag wiki(s).

Comment: Probably can crib from https://stackoverflow.com/q/25991367/18192 for the tag wiki.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: The electrical type of debouncing is roughly the same as the software type.  In both cases, you are ignoring an input activity while it is in process.  In fact, software debounce can often be used to correct for hardware bounce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### This is now done.

The new tag is [debouncing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debouncing), which is a more general description of the concept (`debounce` is often the name of a method that implements that concept).

There is now a synonym from [debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debounce) to [debouncing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debouncing).  The tags have been merged.

The tag wiki excerpt from [debouncing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debouncing) was kept; there was no tag wiki excerpt for [debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debounce).

Answer (score 0):

I edited and added definitions for the tags; I now realize that possibly debouncing is not only a JavaScript concept.

In a JavaScript context, debouncing means executing a handler only every so often, as the browser will fire any event as often as it happens. We have no control over that in userland.

From a lower level perspective, I have absolutely no idea however. Possibly, for driver-writers, debouncing means literally not firing an event as often as the hardware is able to.

Should we strive to cover both these situations in the tags?

If yes, then the current description for debouncing:

> Debouncing ensures that exactly one signal is sent for an event that may be happening several times.

doesn't apply to it, and should not be used in that context, as there is no way for JavaScript code to control how often an event is fired, only how often we react to it.

Comment: Ugh. Whatever. This feels orthogonal to making debouncing and debounce synonyms. Peter's ask of editing the tags made me go sideways in trying to give sense to the tags. They both should be synonyms. Whether or not, and how, we make them apply to what technology is another topic I think.

Comment: Debounce comes up especially often in javascript because debounce is more common in client-side code.  Debounce tends to be used for scenarios where you need to wait for a repetivie activity to be done (scrolling, typing into a search box, etc.) before processing it.  However, server-side code usually knows whether an activity is done or not, so debounce usually isn't needed.

Comment: AFAIK, at a hardware level, one of the areas where the term debouncing is used is related to signals from keyboards.  I suspect it applies to switches fairly generally.  Switches can be noisy gadgets as they are pressed to change state, and debouncing avoids sending spurious signals to the keyboard driver of a terminal.  That's probably not something that crops up in SO questions very often.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That's pretty much the same as the software meaning.  I'm guessing software stole the term from hardware.

Comment: @Brian — me too!